# Embedding model files to jar in Tensorflow Java

Tags: java, tensorflow

I want to embed a pre-trained model in JAR file, and later use it in prediction using Tensorflow's Java API. My Tensorflow version is 1.12.0.

I have tensorflow  model exported in  Python using *tf.saved_model.simple_save*. This saves the PB file and variables to an export directory.  I can successfully load this model in Java using *SavedModelBundle.load* and run predictions as long as the export directory is locally available.

Now I want to use my predictor in a restricted/remote environment as a custom function for Aster Analytics database. This database takes a jar file, and runs a user defined function during SQL calls.

My problem is that *SavedModelBundle*  loads from a local  directory and does not utilize file streams or similar methods  to read resources in a JAR file. As this database has access restrictions, I can not create a permanent local directory and move the exported files there. Similarly, I can not call Tensorflow Serving or any other RPC/REST calls to an external server.

I don't want to create a temp directory and copy exported directory there at each function call (as it may leave left-over directories, and there could be simultaneous  calls  creating race conditions etc.)

**Are there any efficient way to deliver the model in the jar file, and then read it?** I'm hoping there is a way to use SavedModelBundle to read JAR resources. Alternatively, I'm hoping that I can read the model's graph using a file stream, and then initialize variables using  files included in the JAR. However I do not know how to do either.

I appreciate any suggestions and/or directions.

Thx in advance.